# Can't install grub, missing sda?

Tags: linux, centos5, grub

all.

I've been struggling with this for a few hours.

Can't seem to be able to install GRUB.

I'm on a VPS, and what's in /dev looks weird to me:

```
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root     1920 Sep  3 11:51 .
drwxr-xr-x 21 root root     4096 Sep  3 11:55 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root       60 Sep  3 11:51 .udev
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       13 Sep  3 11:51 MAKEDEV -> /sbin/MAKEDEV
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root        4 Sep  3 11:51 X0R -> null
crw-------  1 root root   5,   1 Sep  3 11:51 console
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       11 Sep  3 11:51 core -> /proc/kcore
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       13 Sep  3 11:51 fd -> /proc/self/fd
crw-rw-rw-  1 root root   1,   7 Apr 13  2006 full
crw-r--r--  1 root root  10, 229 Sep  3 11:46 fuse
prw-------  1 root root        0 Sep  3 11:51 initctl
crw-r-----  1 root kmem   1,   2 Apr 13  2006 kmem
crw-------  1 root root   1,  11 Apr 13  2006 kmsg
srw-rw-rw-  1 root root        0 Sep  3 11:51 log
brw-r-----  1 root disk   7,   0 Sep  3 11:51 loop0
brw-r-----  1 root disk   7,   1 Sep  3 11:51 loop1
brw-r-----  1 root disk   7,   2 Sep  3 11:51 loop2
brw-r-----  1 root disk   7,   3 Sep  3 11:51 loop3
brw-r-----  1 root disk   7,   4 Sep  3 11:51 loop4
brw-r-----  1 root disk   7,   5 Sep  3 11:51 loop5
brw-r-----  1 root disk   7,   6 Sep  3 11:51 loop6
brw-r-----  1 root disk   7,   7 Sep  3 11:51 loop7
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root       40 Sep  3 11:51 mapper
brw-------  1 root root   9,   0 Sep  3 11:51 md0
crw-r-----  1 root kmem   1,   1 Apr 13  2006 mem
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root       60 Sep  3 11:51 net
crw-rw-rw-  1 root root   1,   3 Sep  3 11:51 null
crw-rw----  1 root lp    99,   0 Sep  3 11:51 parport0
crw-rw----  1 root lp    99,   1 Sep  3 11:51 parport1
crw-rw----  1 root lp    99,   2 Sep  3 11:51 parport2
crw-rw----  1 root lp    99,   3 Sep  3 11:51 parport3
crw-r-----  1 root kmem   1,   4 Apr 13  2006 port
crw-------  1 root root 108,   0 Sep  3 11:51 ppp
crw-rw-rw-  1 root root   5,   2 Sep  3 12:01 ptmx
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root        0 Sep  3 11:51 pts
crw-rw-rw-  1 root tty    2, 176 Apr 13  2006 ptya0
crw-rw-rw-  1 root tty    2, 177 Apr 13  2006 ptya1
crw-rw-rw-  1 root tty    2, 178 Apr 13  2006 ptya2
crw-rw-rw-  1 root tty    2, 179 Apr 13  2006 ptya3
crw-rw-rw-  1 root tty    2, 180 Apr 13  2006 ptya4
crw-rw-rw-  1 root tty    2, 181 Apr 13  2006 ptya5
crw-rw-rw-  1 root tty    2, 182 Apr 13  2006 ptya6
crw-rw-rw-  1 root tty    2, 183 Apr 13  2006 ptya7
crw-rw-rw-  1 root tty    2, 184 Apr 13  2006 ptya8
crw-rw-rw-  1 root tty    2, 185 Apr 13  2006 ptya9
crw-rw-rw-  1 root tty    2, 186 Apr 13  2006 ptyaa
crw-rw-rw-  1 root tty    2, 187 Apr 13  2006 ptyab
crw-rw-rw-  1 root tty    2, 188 Apr 13  2006 ptyac
crw-rw-rw-  1 root tty    2, 189 Apr 13  2006 ptyad
crw-rw-rw-  1 root tty    2, 190 Apr 13  2006 ptyae
crw-rw-rw-  1 root tty    2, 191 Apr 13  2006 ptyaf
crw-rw-rw-  1 root tty    2,   0 Apr 13  2006 ptyp0
crw-rw-rw-  1 root tty    2,   1 Apr 13  2006 ptyp1
crw-rw-rw-  1 root tty    2,   2 Apr 13  2006 ptyp2
crw-rw-rw-  1 root tty    2,   3 Apr 13  2006 ptyp3
crw-rw-rw-  1 root tty    2,   4 Apr 13  2006 ptyp4
crw-rw-rw-  1 root tty    2,   5 Apr 13  2006 ptyp5
crw-rw-rw-  1 root tty    2,   6 Apr 13  2006 ptyp6
crw-rw-rw-  1 root tty    2,   7 Apr 13  2006 ptyp7
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root        4 Sep  3 11:51 ram -> ram1
brw-r-----  1 root disk   1,   0 Apr 13  2006 ram0
brw-r-----  1 root disk   1,   1 Apr 13  2006 ram1
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root        4 Sep  3 11:51 ramdisk -> ram0
crw-r--r--  1 root root   1,   8 Apr 13  2006 random
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root       40 Sep  3 11:51 shm
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       15 Sep  3 11:51 stderr -> /proc/self/fd/2
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       15 Sep  3 11:51 stdin -> /proc/self/fd/0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       15 Sep  3 11:51 stdout -> /proc/self/fd/1
crw-rw-rw-  1 root root   5,   0 Sep  3 11:51 tty
crw-rw-rw-  1 root tty    3, 176 Apr 13  2006 ttya0
crw-rw-rw-  1 root tty    3, 177 Apr 13  2006 ttya1
crw-rw-rw-  1 root tty    3, 178 Apr 13  2006 ttya2
crw-rw-rw-  1 root tty    3, 179 Apr 13  2006 ttya3
crw-rw-rw-  1 root tty    3, 180 Apr 13  2006 ttya4
crw-rw-rw-  1 root tty    3, 181 Apr 13  2006 ttya5
crw-rw-rw-  1 root tty    3, 182 Apr 13  2006 ttya6
crw-rw-rw-  1 root tty    3, 183 Apr 13  2006 ttya7
crw-rw-rw-  1 root tty    3, 184 Apr 13  2006 ttya8
crw-rw-rw-  1 root tty    3, 185 Apr 13  2006 ttya9
crw-rw-rw-  1 root tty    3, 186 Apr 13  2006 ttyaa
crw-rw-rw-  1 root tty    3, 187 Apr 13  2006 ttyab
crw-rw-rw-  1 root tty    3, 188 Apr 13  2006 ttyac
crw-rw-rw-  1 root tty    3, 189 Apr 13  2006 ttyad
crw-rw-rw-  1 root tty    3, 190 Apr 13  2006 ttyae
crw-rw-rw-  1 root tty    3, 191 Apr 13  2006 ttyaf
crw-rw-rw-  1 root tty    3,   0 Apr 13  2006 ttyp0
crw-rw-rw-  1 root tty    3,   1 Apr 13  2006 ttyp1
crw-rw-rw-  1 root tty    3,   2 Apr 13  2006 ttyp2
crw-rw-rw-  1 root tty    3,   3 Apr 13  2006 ttyp3
crw-rw-rw-  1 root tty    3,   4 Apr 13  2006 ttyp4
crw-rw-rw-  1 root tty    3,   5 Apr 13  2006 ttyp5
crw-rw-rw-  1 root tty    3,   6 Apr 13  2006 ttyp6
crw-rw-rw-  1 root tty    3,   7 Apr 13  2006 ttyp7
crw-r--r--  1 root root   1,   9 Apr 13  2006 urandom
brw-r--r--  1 root root 144,  43 Sep  3 11:51 vzfs
crw-rw-rw-  1 root root   1,   5 Sep  3 11:51 zero
```

I have no sda or hd0, which I guess is needed by GRUB?

Whenever I run grub-install, I get:
No suitable drive was found in the generated device map.

what am I doing wrong?

I'm on CentOS 5.5...

Any help appreciated!

Comment: You probably want to look at the output from df to figure out what your root device is.

Comment: thanks, polynomial, this is what I get (I've been trying to install OpenVZ):
`Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/vzfs             20000000    575984  19424016   3% /
/dev/simfs            20000000    575984  19424016   3% /tmp
/dev/simfs            20000000    575984  19424016   3% /var/tmp
none                    473172         4    473168   1% /dev`

(sorry, I don't get how to format code correctly, no new lines...)

Answer (score 4):

You can't install grub or custom kernel on OpenVZ VPS. It's [OS-level virtualization system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system-level_virtualization).